# How to know the slot connected to specific qobject&signal?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Is it possible, given an object derived from qobject and a specific signal, to dynamically know the slot connected to that signal?

Comment: you mean all connections connected to that signal?

Comment: No.  The question is, why do you need to know?  The point of signals/slots is that the connected objects need not be aware of each other.  You can use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connectNotify if you just need to know if something is connected.  For anything more than that, you will need to keep track of connections yourself, but you'd probably be better off modifying your design so you don't need to.

Comment: I have a QAction connected through the triggered() signal to a given slot. I have to pass this QAction to another part of my program. This other module has to create a new QAction (it cannot be the one I passed) but that must be connected to the same slot when the triggered signal is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `QMetaObject::indexOfSignal`, `QMetaObject::indexOfSlot` and `QMetaObject::indexOfMethod`.

```
QMetaObject* Meta = MyObject->metaObject();
int i = Meta->indexOfSlot("mySlot()");
if (i != -1) {
    // Has connection to slot
}
```

With `QObject::receivers` you returns the number of receivers connected to the signal.

```
if (MyObject->receivers(SIGNAL(mSignal()))) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the slot, you can use QObject::sender() method to get the object which emitted the signal. But i strongly recommend revising your design so you don't need to know the sender.